# Will `if(x=y)` Ever Return false, or fail In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

This is a theoretical question, as I can't imagine any practical uses.

I made a bold statement today saying that in JavaScript, the following will always return true:

```
if (x=y){
    //code
}
```

And the `//code`, whatever it is, will always be executed.

This is the classic typo of not entering `==` or even `===`.

This feature can also be demonstrated in C/C++, but being more strongly-typed languages than JavaScript, it is not hard to think instances where this assignment will fail.

However, in JavaScript, given two variables `x` and `y`, I was struggling to think of an occation where this would fail, or the proceding conditional code block would not execute.

Anyone?

Comment: For the downvoter: If you ever return, please explain why. Downvotes without explanation are pretty useless.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It (x=y) would evaluate to false if y=0, y=null, y=undefined or y=false.

**Edit:** Also if y=NaN

**Edit:** Also if y=""

Comment: To clarify; the expression basically evaluates the value of `y`, hence if `y` equals to `false`, the statement will be false.

Comment: Or NaN or an empty string. Anything that is "falsy": http://www.google.de/search?q=javascript+falsy

Comment: @Tatu -- well, it also sets the value of "x". That could be important.

Comment: @RoToRa, yes I forgot about NaN. Let me fix that. S

Comment: @Ben Lee, yep, but I meant regarding to evaluation, `x` is not meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional block "x=y" will always execute. But in javascript "false", undefined, null, and 0 evaluate to false. So whenever y is one of those values, the "//code" will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
js
js> if(x=y){
print('hello');
}
typein:1: ReferenceError: y is not defined
js>
```